# How large is React in kb?

Tags: reactjs

I like what I see from React - but whenever I hear about it's countless plugins and modules, I actually wonder how much more functionality it has that I have not seen yet, because I haven't actually actively worked with React yet (though I did with JSX through a Babel plugin).

Personally, I wonder how "heavy" React is. My goal is to keep my client-side code as small as possible - I even am considering to render templates on the server for the main pages, and leave smaller templates to the client - so that I have an as complete as possible "shell" being sent from the server to the client, which then enlarges itself as the user progresses through the app. Usually, when I saw usecase examples of React, I saw people render *everything* on the client - for which, I am sure, the client-side code becomes really, really huge.

So before I make any further assumptions of contents that I do not actually know precisely, I would like to see how much React takes alone. For an example consider an easy boilerplate like the ToDo-MVC-ish examples: A router, a couple of controllers, and a couple of views/templates.

Comment: You could use reactCreateApp to create the default sample starting app and easily check in the browser the client size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see it here in [React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#reduced-file-size) blog:

- react is 5.3 kb (2.2 kb gzipped), down from 20.7 kb (6.9 kb gzipped).
- react-dom is 103.7 kb (32.6 kb gzipped), down from 141 kb (42.9 kb
  gzipped).
- react + react-dom is 109 kb (34.8 kb gzipped), down from 161.7 kb
  (49.8 kb gzipped).

You may also check [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/847) further.

If you would like you may install [webpack bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) which will allow you to analyze separate modules like you can see in the image:

[image]

Or, [webpack visualizer](https://github.com/chrisbateman/webpack-visualizer):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can look at https://bundlephobia.com/:

- https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=react
- https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=react-dom

It works for whatever lib you want.